# Mocking in Qunit

Tags: unit-testing, qunit

How do we mock a method in Qunit. I have a situation where I need to mock some methods and return some value. For example I have a function which internally calls the `getBrowser()` function. I want to mock the get browser and pretend as if it is returning a value of "Chrome". Also is there a way of mocking the objects or variables.For example, is there a way of mocking `navigator.userAgent`? Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way of mocking functions by default in QUnit, but you can try some plugins. Never tried them myself, but this page references a few mocking tools :
[QUnit Plugins](https://qunitjs.com/plugins/)